# Loading Owl Carousel 2 with AngularJS dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, owl-carousel-2

I can't load owl carousel in a angularjs dynamic content.

I use this (edited) html:

```
<div id="Galeria" owlcarousel class="youplay-carousel gallery-popup">
      <a class="angled-img" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{video}}" ng-repeat="video in juego.Galerias.Videos">
         <div class="img">
            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/{{video}}/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
         </div>
         <i class="fa fa-play icon"></i>
      </a>

      <a class="angled-img" href="/img/galerias/{{imagen}}" ng-repeat="imagen in juego.Galerias.Imagenes">
         <div class="img">
            <img src="/img/galerias/{{imagen}}" alt="">
         </div>
         <i class="fa fa-search-plus icon"></i>
      </a>
   </div>
```

and this (edited) directive to my app:

```
app.directive('owlcarousel', function() {

    var linker = function(scope, element, attr) {
        var loadCarousel = function() {
            console.log(element);
            element.owlCarousel({
                loop: !0,
                stagePadding: 70,
                nav: !0,
                autoplay: 0 ? !0 : !1,
                autoplayTimeout: 0,
                autoplaySpeed: 600,
                autoplayHoverPause: !0,
                navText: ["", ""],
                responsive: {
                    0: {
                        items: 1
                    },
                    500: {
                        items: 2
                    },
                    992: {
                        items: 3
                    },
                    1200: {
                        items: 4
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        scope.$watch("juego.Galerias.Videos", function(value) {
            loadCarousel(element);
        });

        scope.$watch("juego.Galerias.Imagenes", function(value) {
            loadCarousel(element);
        })
    }

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linker
    }

});
```

But i can't load the carousel every time i load new content. I try to bind jquery event, call function in controller...etc.

PD: I use ng-routes and load html dinamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass models to directive scope, and then do `scope.$watch` and reinit owlCarousel with `reinit` method. It is just an idea, if you could specify plunkr or fiddle it would be easier to help.

Comment: I modify my script (see above) and trying to execute this script directly (http://pastebin.com/xxcSLbTv) but the console only retrieve me a dom element: https://gyazo.com/a79fce0ff98e0a379f150a84d40247d9